# Multiple format specifiers, Java format

Tags: java, format

How can I apply multiple format specifiers for a number in Java? For example, if I want to show a floating point number to two decimal places, left justified with 10 characters, and showing a % sign how would I do this? i.e.

20.00%

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method. Using correct [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) you can do all of what you need in one line.